# How to display 2 fragments side by side in landscape

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have an Activity1 hosting `ListFragmentA`.
On clicking an item of the list I launch Activity2 hosting `ListFragmentB`.
Both in portrait and landscape I see 1 list at a time.
I am interested when I am in landscape mode (or in a tablet I guess for that matter) to see both fragments.
I.e. the `ListFragmentA` in the left side of the display and the `ListFragmentB` in the right. So that when the user presses an item from `ListFragmentA` the correct data in `ListFragmentB` are displayed.
How is this done? Via layouts in landscape mode seems to me tedious/wrong and not sure how it is done to be honest.
Is there a good example I could look into?

Comment: Maybe this will help
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-fragment-example.html

Answer (score 1):

The fragment_layout.xml for portrait mode is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="edu.dartmouth.cs.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In landscape mode a single activity (FragmentLayout) handles both the fragments. We will also consider inserting a fragment programmatically. Consider the landscape res/layout-land/fragment_layout.

The fragment_layout.xml for landscape mode is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="edu.dartmouth.cs.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you comment out the line of code shown below in TitlesFragment: onActivityCreated() (which is called when the FragmentLayout onCreate() has returned) then you will see the blank on loaded form the frame_layout above. If the line is not added back then the DetailsFragment is not loaded into the until the user selects an item from the list - at that point the DetailsFragment is created and placed into the FrameLayout.

```
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                                    **snippet**

                                    if (mDualPane) {
                                                // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
                                                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                                                // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
                        showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
                                    } else {
```

FragmentLayout (main activity) applies a layout in the usual way, during onCreate():

```
public class FragmentLayout extends Activity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                        // root view inflated
                        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
            }
```

When In the user clicks on one the items in the ListFragment then onListItemClick() callback is called which in turn calls the showDetails(position) to will start

```
 @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "onListItemClick position is" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            showDetails(position);
        }
```

TitlesFragment

The fragment uses a helper function to show details of a selected item.

```
 public static class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {
        boolean mDualPane;
        int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

        // onActivityCreated() is called when the activity's onCreate() method
        // has returned.

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // You can use getActivity(), which returns the activity associated
            // with a fragment.
            // The activity is a context (since Activity extends Context) .

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TitlesFragment:onActivityCreated",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Populate list with our static array of titles in list in the
            // Shakespeare class
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                    Shakespeare.TITLES));

            // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
            // fragment directly in the containing UI.
            // R.id.details relates to the res/layout-land/fragment_layout.xml
            // This is first created when the phone is switched to landscape
            // mode

            View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "detailsFrame " + detailsFrame,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Check that a view exists and is visible
            // A view is visible (0) on the screen; the default value.
            // It can also be invisible and hidden, as if the view had not been
            // added.
            //
            mDualPane = detailsFrame != null
                    && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mDualPane " + mDualPane,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // Restore last state for checked position.
                mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
            }

            if (mDualPane) {
                // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected
                // item.
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
                showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
            } else {
                // We also highlight in uni-pane just for fun
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                getListView().setItemChecked(mCurCheckPosition, true);
            }
        }
```

Managing state between orientation flips
The app keep track of the current checked selection so when it resumes it -- say back again in landscape it as the last position highlighted using onSaveInstanceState() in the fragment lifecycle. The fragment saves its current dynamic state, so it can later be reconstructed in a new instance of its process is restarted. If a new instance of the fragment later needs to be created, the data you place in the Bundle here will be available in the Bundle given to onCreate(Bundle), onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), and onActivityCreated(Bundle). In the code the new fragment restores the state in onActivityCreated(). State here is just the mCurCheckPosition.

```
 @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onSaveInstanceState",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
        }
```

FragmentManager and Fragment Transactions

Helper function (showDetails(position)) to show the details of a selected item, either by displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a whole new activity in which it is displayed.

```
 void showDetails(int index) {
            mCurCheckPosition = index;

            // The basic design is mutli-pane (landscape on the phone) allows us
            // to display both fragments (titles and details) with in the same
            // activity; that is FragmentLayout -- one activity with two
            // fragments.
            // Else, it's single-pane (portrait on the phone) and we fire
            // another activity to render the details fragment - two activities
            // each with its own fragment .
            //
            if (mDualPane) {
                // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
                // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
                // We keep highlighted the current selection
                getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

                // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
                DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.details);
                if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
                    // Make new fragment to show this selection.

                    details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "showDetails dual-pane: create and replace fragment",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
                    // with this one inside the frame.
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.commit();
                }

            } else {
                // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
                // the dialog fragment with selected text.
                // That is: if this is a single-pane (e.g., portrait mode on a
                // phone) then fire DetailsActivity to display the details
                // fragment

                // Create an intent for starting the DetailsActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                // explicitly set the activity context and class
                // associated with the intent (context, class)
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);

                // pass the current position
                intent.putExtra("index", index);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

DetailsActivity: Portrait mode processing

As discussed before If the user clicks a list item and the current layout does not include the R.id.details view (DetailsFragment does this), then the application starts the DetailsActivity activity to display the content of the item. The helper function creates a new fragment in landscape to draw the details in portrait starts an activity (DetailsActivity) to manage the detail fragment -- that is create a new DetailsFragment and add it to the root view using FragmentManager, as shown below. The DetailsActivity embeds the DetailsFragment to display the selected play summary when the screen is in portrait orientation:

// This is a secondary activity, to show what the user has selected when the
// screen is not large enough to show it all in one activity.

public static class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Toast.makeText(this, "DetailsActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // If the screen is now in landscape mode, we can show the
        // dialog in-line with the list so we don't need this activity.
        finish();
        return;
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.

        // create fragment
        DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();

        // get and set the position input by user (i.e., "index")
        // which is the construction arguments for this fragment
        details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        //
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
    }
}
```

}

DetailsFragment

The fragment is first created. The fragment lifecycle ensures that onCreateView() to build the layout for the fragment. It builds the fragment with a textview -- text.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]) -- and attaches it to a scroller (ScrollView) and returns (and rendered) the view which is drawn.

```
    // This is the secondary fragment, displaying the details of a particular
    // item.        

    public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

                **snippet**

                public int getShownIndex() {
                            return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
                }

                // The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its
                // user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment,
                // you must return a View from this method that is the root of your
                // fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not
                // provide a UI.

                // We create the UI with a scrollview and text and return a reference to
                // the scoller which is then drawn to the screen

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    **snippet**

                        // programmatically create a scrollview and textview for the text in
                        // the container/fragment layout. Set up the properties and add the view

                        ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
                        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
                        int padding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                                            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getActivity()
                                                          .getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                        text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
                        scroller.addView(text);
                        text.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]);
                        return scroller;
                }
    }
```

Comment: You've gone to a lot of trouble to build what appears to be a complete example only to have left out a lot of details. What's with the **snippet**s?